# Is this Java reply to a job questionnaire valid?

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked this in WRITTEN form through a recruiter, with the previous question being string related, and the previous one being about Inversion of Control:

How would you find the second largest element in an array?

Being a Project manager who has is self teaching/learning JAVA, my response was:

How is large defined (integers? parsing of: strings/objects? )   How large is the array? Bubble sort , then return the second to last index.   Temporarily store the largest and second to largest variable, sort through the array, replacing the appropriate variables, then return the second largest variable.   There are many ways, however to develop an appropriate function that isn’t expensive would require more information.   If the range is very wide, make several lean methods, measure the array length, and apply the appropriate method on the array.

Is this a valid response to the question, and if not, what do you think it needs improvement on?  I'm asking this because of the extreme gap presented in the common recruitment atmosphere, and am having difficult understanding the actual intended purpose of similar structured questions, and need your feedback to understand what/how to approach/reply.

**UPDATE** I received notification that they typically see code, but provided no parameters or guidelines, and replied with this:

> I can not provide a codified answer, not knowing at least the first two pieces of information.  The first will allow for parsing, as numbers are sorted universally, while strings, objects, and others are parsed subjectively.  The second part, dealing with the array length, and whether or not it is static, is definitely relavent as a developer, as expensive code (whether in computation time facing the user, or hardware costs to the client) can be costly. The question is worded poorly for an exact technical response, especially given that it is in written format, where there is no feedback.   I am merely typing my considerations as a reply, the same as if it were asked in person.   The context I am given from the previous questions is that they are looking for someone who understands IoC practices (bullet 3) and would be parsing Strings (given bullet 2) in potentially a transaction (try/catch) situation (bullet 4) and then find (current issue). If the questionnaire's purpose is to see how I approach a problem, then my response is valid.   If they would like further clarification, I would be happy to accomodate, but if they are requiring a codified answer AND unwilling to provide the necessary context, then I am unwilling to work with them, as it would highlight there misunderstanding of how to interact with external customers, who DO need guidance when one "simple" question is asked, but other pieces of information are needed to best accommodate, the central reason behind any business seeking outside specialized help. I hope this response in not read in a harsh tone, as my cadence when replying out loud is quite the opposite, as further information is required, including if sole development in JAVA is within the scope of this job, as I am skilled in JS and Python as well, and this was not discussed yesterday.  Hopefully you and your client can understand that with the recruiter method, a layer of abstraction can be beneficial in many areas, but in situations like this, it can hinder and cloud perceptions without direct communication and feedback. Please feel free to provide this in addition to my answer.

and received acclaim for this reply.  Thank you for your help, as I am really trying to get a programming job, but have no prior formal experience and this guidance really helps.

Comment: I think thats the whole point of asking the question, to see what sort of response you come out with.  Its not really for others to comment on in my opinion.

Comment: Bubble sort is a poor sorting method.  I haven't heard of someone actually using it except while learning about how to sort arrays.

Comment: Sometimes people are looking for an expected answer, which may be simpler than what you have in mind.  You need to judge on how much detail to give as well. I start with the simplest possible answer first and elaborate if I have time.

Comment: I bet they expect an answer in the lines of "Run through the array keeping track of the top two elements. Return the lesser one."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I think the interviewer really wants to know in order to find 2nd largest element, does one have to **sort the entire array**(and pick the second element) or is there any **better approach**?

The answer is you don't have to sort the entire array in order to find top k elements. Sorting will take O(nlgn) time whereas finding top k items will take only O(nlogk).

You can explain the answer using simple example. If you have to find 2nd largest card in 100 cards with numbers ranging some low to high. The cards are not sorted. To find 2nd largest card, all of you have to do is hold top 2 cards that you have seen so far in your hand. As you pick new cards, see if it is larger than the one in your hand, if so replace the new largest with the smallest in hand. At the end of this process, you will end up holding top 2 cards.

**EDIT:** Like others said, bubble sort has worst runtime O(n^2). For fun, Check out President Obama's answer to sorting interview question. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient to do the needed task is obvious: iterate once on the array and looking for the "largest" element, all the while storing also the previous "largest" element. At the end of the array, your previous "largest" element is the one your method needs to return.

To formulate your answer, I see 2 choices:

- Beginning your answer by "Assuming the array contains int elements..." or something approaching.
- Using an undefined isLargest() or isLarger() method and explain that the purpose of the method is to check if the current element is largest currently examined, whatever it means.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty subjective, but frankly I agree with your question-about-the-question -- they should have defined what it is your array contains.

What you could have done is written something like "Assuming the elements in the array are all integers, here's how I'd do it" and then give your answer with that assumption.

I'd follow the same steps with your other requests for additional info -- make an assumption, *declare your assumption*, then proceed with that assumption in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Seems valid - I just fear they wanted CODE. I think maybe you should have just assumed integers and written something IN ADDITION to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

My initial gut reaction would be "Modified Merge Sort", implemented using a ForkJoinPool.  It's still O(n log[n]), but the actual runtime would be faster than a serial implementation.

You may ask why not quicksort, and it's because worst case for quicksort is O(n^2), which would be bad for an extremely large dataset.  Modified Merge Sort has more predictable performance and a better worst case scenario O(n log[n])